# regex python to transform

Tags: python, regex

I would like to know what is the regular expression to transform a string that starts with a minus sign, followed by a comma and a sequence of digits, such as -.13082, into a string that starts with a minus sign followed by the first digit of the previous sequence, followed by a dot and then the rest of the digits.

This would transform  `-.13082` to `-1.3082`  or `-.26750` to `-2.6750`

thank you

Comment: Depending on your use case, wouldn't it be easier to convert to int, check if it's lower than 0, then multiplying by 10? (and maybe convert it back to string)

Comment: This should be a simple use of capture groups and back-references in the replacement string. What have you tried?

Comment: There's no comma in your strings. `.` is decimal point (or period, or full stop), `,` is comma.

Comment: @Zembla The comment says "multiplying by 10", not "divide by 10" (`-.75` is a shorthand for `-0.75`). Be aware of [floating point maths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) though. You might want to use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library.

Comment: sorry Vvld and 3limin4t0r , with Vvld solution it's work.  I receive the value in string format. But by converting it to a float and multiplying by 10, it works. Jules' regex solution also works (see below), but I need to test if the value is less than zero, so this solution is better for me. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Do you have basic knowledge of Regular Expressions ? What have you tried to get that knowledge to answer your own question ?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex groups. One for the minus sign, one for the first digit, one for the remainder of the digits.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(-)\.(\d)(.*)', r'\1\2.\3',  "-.13082")
'-1.3082'
>>> re.sub(r'(-)\.(\d)(.*)', r'\1\2.\3', "-.26750")
'-2.6750'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern with the *[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.sub)* method—swapping the . with the captured value.

```
\.(\d)
```

```py
string = '-.13082'
string = re.sub(r'\.(\d)', r'\1.', string)
```

```
-1.3082
```

Alternately, if the locations are static, you can swap the character indices using a *[list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)* class, and re-concatenate with *[str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)*.

```py
string = '-.13082'
chars = list(string)
chars[1], chars[2] = chars[2], chars[1]
string = ''.join(chars)
```

Comment: Note that this would also convert `-9.876` into `-98.76`. To prevent that make sure there is no decimal before the point. `r'(?<!\d)\.(\d)'`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, well, of course.  They had stated, _"... a string that starts with a minus sign, followed by a comma and a sequence of digits ..."_, though.